# How to display event as color dots in fullcalendar?

Tags: json, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I have used fullcalendar3.2.0 plugin. It's work great, i read data from JSON.
I need to show all events as color dots as above image. How to customize this. Kindly look into this.

[image: FullCalendar3.2.0]

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 4):

CSS may work for you https://jsfiddle.net/2kov1y7v/

```
a.fc-event {
  border-radius: 10px; /* round edges */
  width: 15px; /* fixed width */
  color: transparent; /* hide text */
}


/* inline the tr's for events */
div.fc-content-skeleton > table > tbody > tr {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Just tested it with more events occuring later in the week and they all get bunched together in the first cell. Sorry, this is probably not a good solution but may give you an idea for a better one

Comment: It doesn't work in my application. could you please give the another solution?

Comment: I looked into it further and given how the events get rendered, it will be no easy feat. **Have you made any attempts yourself?**

Comment: This doesn't work if an event lasts for more than a day.

Answer (score 2):

I got same problem for one of my project, here is my solution :

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    ....
    lazyFetching: false,
    eventSources: [
        {
            url : '08mn7li1nmriqc6sktvjq6gluk@group.calendar.google.com',
            color: '#ea4647',
            className: 'holidays-event holidays-french-event'
        }, {
            url: 'fr.french#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com',
            color: '#06b981',
            className: 'holidays-event holidays-day-event'
        }
    ],
    eventAfterAllRender: function() {
        var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
        if (view.type == 'basicWeek' || view.type == 'basicDay') {
            return false;
        }

        // reset calendar dots
        $('#calendar').find('.fc-day-number').find('.fc-event').remove();

        // manage dots
        var events = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
        for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
            var event = events[i];
            if (event.source.url === '08mn7li1nmriqc6sktvjq6gluk@group.calendar.google.com') {
                // build dots holidays for specific source
                var name = event.title;
                var now = event.start.clone();

                // loop through event dates
                while (now.isBefore(event.end)) {
                    var $dot = $('<span class="fc-day-grid-event fc-event fc-start fc-not-end dot-event" title=""></span>');

                    // add bootstrap popover for dot
                    $dot.popover({
                        'content': name,
                        'trigger': 'hover',
                        'container': '#calendar',
                        'placement': 'bottom'
                    });

                    // append to calendar day
                    $('.fc-day-number[data-date="'+ now.format('YYYY-MM-DD') +'"]').append($dot);
                    now.add(1, 'days');
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And CSS for dot effect :

```
#calendar .dot-event {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
```

Comment: The above solution isn't working. `var events = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');` is showing 0 length.

Answer (score 0):

```
backgroundColor: 'red' // override!

events: [
           {
               title: 'Title ',
               constraint: 'availableForMeeting',
               start: new Date(),
               end: new Date(),
               allDay: true,
               url: '/x/1/edit',
               backgroundColor: 'red' // override!
           },
]
```